# Calculation of RO(G)-graded cohomology of a point

Tags: equivariant-cohomology

Recently I have been learning about some calculation of  RO(G)-graded cohomology of a point from J.L. Caruso's paper on "Operations in equivariant Z/p-cohomology".
My question is how to calculate RO(G)-graded cohomology of (Z/n)/(Z/d) with a constant Mackey functor, where d|n and d> 1? precisely,which kind of Z/n - cofiber sequences should I use to calculate the above cohomology?
Need some hint.